# Alfresco Custom Content Type not showing

Tags: maven, alfresco, m2eclipse, alfresco-share

I have been trying to follow this tutorial about Alfresco custom content types

http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html#localizing-strings-for-custom-content-models.

However, when I get to the 'Test your changes' step and I go to manage rules, I can't manage to get the custom types created (sc_doc and sc_whitepaper) in the dropdown list.

My share-config-custom.xml:

```
<!-- Share configuration related to this particular Share module extension, such as:
     - Doclib action config
     - Form config
     - Aspect and Type config

    Note. Any configuration related to the whole Share.war webapp
           (i.e. not specific to this share extension) should be
            placed in the environment specific config:
             alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml file
     -->
<alfresco-config>
<!-- Document Library config section -->
 <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
  <aspects>
    <!-- Aspects that a user can see -->
        <visible>
          <aspect name="sc:webable" />
          <aspect name="sc:productRelated" />            
        </visible>
    <!-- Aspects that a user can add. Same as "visible" if left empty -->
        <addable>
        </addable>
    <!-- Aspects that a user can remove. Same as "visible" if left empty -->
        <removeable>
        </removeable>
  </aspects>
  </config>
  <config evaluator="node-type" condition="DocumentLibrary">
  <types>
    <type name="cm:content">
        <subtype name="sc:doc" />
        <subtype name="sc:whitepaper" />
    </type>
    <type name="sc:doc">
        <subtype name="sc:whitepaper" />
    </type>
  </types>
</config>    
</alfresco-config>
```

PS: Do I have to re-run 'mvn install' after every change I make in the .xml using Eclipse?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: yes you need to rerun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know i am posting this answer bit late
and my solution is bit poor, But it works for me :)
I hope it will also work for you.
Strange thing is i am following same tutorial and at the time of                     'Test your changes' stage not able to see my custom types on the server.

so to make it working in my share project i have changed place of
 share-config-custom.xml
from `src/main/resources/META-INF` to  `src/main/amp/config/alfresco/web-extension`
and restart alfresco and now able to view my custom types in type list on server.
plz post your answer if you have make done this by any other way :)
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which kind of project you have created from maven artifacts.

- Repository AMP archetype
- All-In-One (AIO) archetype
- Share AMP archetype

Here you can see list of all [maven commands](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/alfresco-sdk-cmd-reference.html).

If you are not using local maven repository then you can go for **"mvn package"** to generate new AMP files and then deploy them manually on alfresco server.

Comment: Hi @mitpato! Thanks for your answer, I haven't answered back due to lack of knowledge and self-confidence. I have been reading a bit about Alfresco and it's customizations and maybe now you can help me.
I created 2 artifacts, one for repo and one for share. I was following the guide from the link and when adding a new folder rule, I was supposed to see new content types in 'Content of type or sub-type' criteria. However, it's only available the 4 default Alfresco aspects.